# Reverse Partial Match in Google Sheets using query, index, iferror, regexextract

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

original document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fD6-KFv_Qh_a4NXBPC1qAT8U7g6YNTv7YyLAS4lAN9o/edit?usp=sharing

I want to compare the word in range B3:C3 that partially match the word on the list in another sheet "prevodi" and give that corresponding exact match. in my case that would be Angleščina.

My formula is written in C1

Can u pls help how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; Prevodi!A2:A))))
```